# How do I password-lock a tmux client?

Tags: security, tmux

I have the following `.tmux.conf` lines:

```
# Enable locking
set -g lock-command vlock
set -g lock-after-time 0 # Seconds; 0 = never
bind l lock-client
bind L lock-session
```

Pressing `[prefix]` + `L` (capital) locks my session.

I want to be able to press `[prefix]` + `L` to lock the client, but it's ignored.

How can I lock just the current client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `[prefix]`+`?` in tmux to verify if your key bindings actually took effect: they might conflict with an existing mapping.

You can also use `[prefix]`+`:` to enter `tmux` commands in long form: press that key combination, then type in `lock-client` or `lock-session` and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks, with your help I realised that in my long-ish `.tmux.conf` I'd overwritten that binding later on. I updated the question with the `.` too.